# What controller for a 400W AC-DC SMPS?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, mains, ac-dc

I would like to build a big AC-DC SMPS. I built a little one based on ST's VIPer22A. This is a nice little IC that can give up to a couple watts (my design was 5V 1A). It was easy enough to design using ST's online tools: it calculates all the required component values (especially the transformer).

But, for a 400W supply (50V 8A) it goes a little out of spec for the tool. The IC they recommend is L6566B. The transformer is much larger than what the tool is able to handle (EE60 core), and it requires litz type wire for all coils. I'd prefer if litz wasn't a requirement.

What IC is there that can handle this kind of power AND offers some sort of tool to calculate the required transformer?

I know anything mains-related is dangerous by its nature, but I have the tools for this (an isolation transformer, for starters).

Comment: For 400 watts you are starting to get into a specialized area where the possible solution might be a H-bridge driven primary and it's unlikely that you will find an online tool that will cover this but, please let me know if you do.

Comment: @Andyaka Well, I didn't find an automatic tool but the closest thing I found was this reference design: http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slou293c/slou293c.pdf It's relatively complicated because it offers all features (like PFC and the standby supply), and also it's a "Class G" supply, intended to be used with TI's TAS5630, which is an audio amplifier with a "CLIP" output. When this output is on, the amp is "about to clip", and the supply changes to higher Vout (to keep dissipation low at low volumes).